# XSLT conditional apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt

**Setup :** Apache Xalan 2.7.1

**Input :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
        <p>
            <code>111</code>
            <attr>good</attr>
        </p>
        <p>
            <code>222</code>
            <attr>bad</attr>
        </p>

        <s>
            <ps>
                <p>
                    <code>111</code>
                </p>
            <ps>
        </s>
        <s>
            <ps>
                <p>
                    <code>222</code>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <code>333</code>
                </p>
            <ps>
        </s>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
                  root[./p/code = ./s/ps[1]/p/code and ./p/attr= 'bad']/s" />
  </xsl:template>



 <xsl:template match="s">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Select :**

I would like to select only those `s` which has first `p` in `s/ps` with `code` that points out to `p` element with `bad` `attr`

> **Note: Only xslt 1.0 solutions are appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a key to look up the `p` elements

```
<xsl:key name="attr" match="root/p" use="code" />
```

Then your `xsl:apply-templates` simplifies to this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/s[key('attr', ps/p[1]/code)/attr = 'bad']" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="attr" match="root/p" use="code" />

    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/s[key('attr', ps/p[1]/code)/attr = 'bad']" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="s">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```